# How to update woocommerce products statuses to private in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin, product, wordpress-admin

I want to change a specific range of products to "private".

I am using this query to display my products:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `ID` BETWEEN 2044 AND 2048
AND `post_type` = 'product'
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```

I want to change post_status from "publish" to "private".

What will I write in console, can someone help?

phpMyadmin:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following `sql query` to change your products statuses:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_status = 'private' 
WHERE ID BETWEEN 2044 AND 2048
AND post_type = 'product'
```

**NOTE:**

- I've used `wp_` as the table prefix. It's important to change it if your table prefix is different.
- This query updates only the products where `post_status` is equal to 'product'.

---

To update all of products where `post_status` is equal to 'product' or 'product_variation', use the following `sql query`:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_status = 'private' 
WHERE ID BETWEEN 2044 AND 2048
AND post_type = 'product'
OR post_type = 'product_variation'
```

This answer has been tested and works!